# Firestore perform compound query, event "MODIFIED" not intercepted

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a model "Post" composed by these attributes:

```
class Post {
   String timestamp;
   Boolean isActive;
}
```

If I try (in my Android app) to querying my collection "posts" on my Firestore DB with this query:

[1]

```
db.collection("posts")
        .whereEqualTo("isActive", true)
        .orderBy("timestamp",Direction.DESCENDING)
        .limit(3);
```

The documents appear into my `RecyclerView` correctly but if I Update by the webConsole of Firestore an attribute of my document(for example isActive), the event "modified" is not intercepted into the case "MODIFIED" of the switch used to intercept the real time updates of my collection.

Otherwhise, if I deleting from the above query the condition `.whereEqualTo("isActive", true)` all works fine.

[2]

```
db.collection("posts")
        .orderBy("timestamp",Direction.DESCENDING)
        .limit(3);
```

Otherwhise, if I deleting from the [1] query the condition .limit(3) all works fine.

[3]

```
db.collection("posts")
        .whereEqualTo("isActive", true)
        .orderBy("timestamp",Direction.DESCENDING);
```

This is the code:

```
Query query = db.collection("posts")
.whereEqualTo("isActive", true)
.orderBy("timestamp",Direction.DESCENDING)
.limit(3);

ListenerGetPost = query.addSnapshotListener(
    new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot snapshots,
                            @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

            for (DocumentChange doc : snapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                switch (doc.getType()) {
                    case ADDED:
                        Post post = doc.getDocument().toObject(Post.class);
                        mPostList.add(post);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        break;
                    case MODIFIED:
                        //Do something...
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Comment: No man...  I don't know how to solve the problem

Comment: It will be helpful for you if I'll write you the solution?

Comment: Yes, I would appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

When using a query that looks like this:

```
db.collection("posts")
    .whereEqualTo("isActive", true)
    .orderBy("timestamp",Direction.DESCENDING)
    .limit(3);
```

It's mandatory to create an **[index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing)**. This can be simply done by creating it manually in your Firebase Console, or by running your app and copy and paste the link that appears in the logcat directly into your browser. Then the index will be created automatically. Just take a look in your logcat after this warning:

```
FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index. You can create it here: ...
```